# EXCEL VBA: loop through each column to change the data format

Tags: excel, vba

Because I can only change the data format for only one column I need a loop which counts from column "E:E" to column "GN:GN" to change the format for each column.

I tried it like this:

```
Sub Format()

Dim intCol As Long

For intCol = 5 To 196 ' this would be E to GN??

Columns("intCol").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("intCol""1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
    
  
Next intCol

End Sub
```

i need to go over data format, because i have this format right now (it doesnt change with "normal" NumberFormat):
[image]

It would be so nice, if someone could help me out!

Comment: `Columns("intCol")` does not have any (correct) meaning... You can use `Cells(1, intCol).EntireColumn` and ` `Cells(1, intCol)` instead of `Range("intCol""1")`, which is also a strange construction... Besides that, selecting does not bring any benefit. Use directly `Cells(1, intCol).EntireColumn.TextToColumns  ...`

Answer (score 1):

What are you talking about?

Hereby a screenshot (I've hidden most columns for readability):

[image]

In VBA:

```
Range("E1:GN1048576").NumberFormat = "0.00"
```

Or, as I find readability important:

```
Columns("C:GN").NumberFormat = "0.00"
```

Comment: thanks for your help(: ,  i tried this before... i edited my post with more info.